# AWK split file by separator and count

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a large 220mb file.  The file is grouped by a horizontal row "---".  This is what I have so far:

```
    cat test.list | awk -v ORS="" -v RS="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" '{print $0;}'
```

How do I take this and print to a new file every 1000 matches?

Is there another way to do this?  I looked at split, and csplit but the "----" rows to not occur predictably so I have to match them, and then split on a count of the matches.

I would like the output files to groups of 1000 matches per file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output the first 1000 records to `outputfile0`, the next to `outputfile1`, etc., just do:

```
awk 'NR%1000 == 1{ file = "outputfile" i++ } { print > file }' ORS= RS=------ test.list
```

(Note that I truncated the dashes in RS for simplicity.)'

Unfortunately, using a value of `RS` that is more than a single character produces unspecified results, so the above cannot be the solution.  Perhaps something like twalberg's solution is required:

```
awk '/^----$/ { if(!(c%1000)) count+=1; c+=1; next } 
    {print > ("outputfile"count)}' c=1 count=1
```

Comment: This solution works mostly, however all files except the first one start with an empty line now.

Comment: Is there an empty line after each `----------` record separator?

Comment: No, there are no empty lines in the input. In the result though, the records are separated by a newline (after all, the separator is `---` and not `---\n`) and hence the first record in a new file is "separated" by a newline.

Comment: Ack!  Got stuck in gnu awk mode.  In standard awk, `RS` can only be a single character, and the results are unspecified if more than one character is used, so you really do need to use an approach like twalberg suggests.

Comment: This is GNU Awk 4.0.1, so this should not be the problem. As far as I understand the original question, records are separated by '---\n'. From my understanding of Awk, RS='---' does not include the newline, so each record (apart from the first one), does really start with a `\n`. Setting RS="---\n" solves that, but then there is no separation between records in the output at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something along these lines might work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {fileno=1,matchcount=0}
     /^-------/ { if (++matchcount == 1000) { ++fileno; matchcount=0; } }
                { print $0 > "output_file_" fileno }' < test.list
```

It might be cleaner to put all that in, say `split.awk` and use `awk -f split.awk test.list` instead...